# Wide table inside div - div not stretching

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want a parent div to stretch when the child table width goes beyond page width.

what would be the best css solution for this?

Comment: A `div` will normally expand to fit its content; what styles are you applying to the table's parent `div` (and the `table` itself)?

Comment: no styles at all - the example is just simple html - I'm guessing the problem is because the table goes beyond browser width

Comment: Okay, so what mark-up are you using? Can you post a demo? I recommend using either [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) for this, just so we can see what you're seeing.

Comment: check the source of the example link to see code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the div to `display: inline-block` appears to do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the quick response

- this probably is not the most elegant solution
- but for the mini site I'm building this will be good enough

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table;` as well. (DIV)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (XHTML transitional 1.0 doctype) I had structure like

```
<div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <img width="1800px" height="600px" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

As I found in CSS rules, table had

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

When I removed this rule, everything got fixed.